# How to solve "These credentials do not match our records" error while login. Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to login to my admin panel in localhost but each time getting an error, "These credentials do not match our records". I have tried creating a new user but getting the same error. 
Below is my database.php code

```
    'connections' => [
    'sqlite' => [
        'driver' => 'sqlite',
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', database_path('database.sqlite')),
        'prefix' => '',
    ],

    'mysql' => [
        'driver' => 'mysql',
        'host' => env('DB_HOST', '127.0.0.1'),
        'port' => env('DB_PORT', '3306'),
        'database' => env('DB_DATABASE', 'forge'),
        'username' => env('DB_USERNAME', 'forge'),
        'password' => env('DB_PASSWORD', ''),
        'unix_socket' => env('DB_SOCKET', ''),
        'charset' => 'utf8',
        'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
        'prefix' => '',
        'strict' => true,
        'engine' => null,
    ],
```

Since I'm new to Laravel, so I'm Unable to understand why is this happening. Kindly help me to solve this problem.

Comment: are you hashing the user's password when creating?

Comment: yes user passwords are being hashed